# How to calculate this limit nth root series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Evaluate $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\sqrt[n]{k}-\sqrt[n]{n}\right).$$

I tried to resolve that limit but all I found via a comparative with integral of x^(1/n) is that if the limit above exist it must be between -2 and -1 and by another approach I found that it must be <=-3/2.
I really want to know if a specific value can be found.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Why do you think the limit must be between $-1$ and $-2$? What do you get for $s(7)$? I seem to get about $-2.2$; it seems the sum is below $-2$ for $n>2$ and it would not surprise me if the limit was $-2$ approached from below

Comment: $k$ from 0 to n-1.$$k\le t\le k+1\Rightarrow \int_{k}^{k+1}\sqrt[n]{k}dt\le \int_{k}^{k+1}\sqrt[n]{t} dt\le \int_{k}^{k+1}\sqrt[n]{k+1}dt$$$$\Rightarrow \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sqrt[n]{k}\le \int_{0}^{n}\sqrt[n]{t} dt\le \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sqrt[n]{k+1}$$$$\Rightarrow\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sqrt[n]{k}\le \frac{n^{2}\sqrt[n]{n}}{n+1}\le \sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt[n]{k}$$$$\Rightarrow -\frac{2n+1}{n+1}\sqrt[n]{n}\le \sum_{k=0}^{n} (\sqrt[n]{k}-\sqrt[n]{n})\le - \frac{n}{n+1}\sqrt[n]{n}$$And we have$$\lim_{n \to +\infty } -\frac{2n+1}{n+1} \sqrt[n]{n}=-2\text{ And } \lim_{n \to +\infty } -\frac{n}{n+1}\sqrt[n]{n}=-1$$

Comment: This is what comparing to the integral gives me. $s(7)$ yeah I get the same result but the limit must be between $-2$ and $-1$. I would like to know if it could be $-2$ or a specific value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Euler McLaurin Summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula#Asymptotic_expansion_of_sums) I believe the answer comes out to be $-2$.

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{1/n} \approx \int_{1}^{n} x^{1/n} \text{d}x + \frac{n^{1/n} + 1}{2} + \mathcal{O}(1/n^{(2-1/n)})$$

$$ \approx \frac{n^{2+1/n}}{n+1} - \frac{n}{n+1}  + \frac{n^{1/n} + 1}{2} + \mathcal{O}(1/n)$$

$$ \approx \frac{n^{2+1/n}}{n+1} $$

Thus our limit is same as the limit of

$$ \frac{n^{2+1/n}}{n+1}  -(n+1)n^{1/n}$$

$$ = n^{1/n}\left(\frac{n^2}{n+1} - (n+1)\right)$$

Which comes out to be $$-2$$

Comment: It seems correct. I would like to know how we get the comparison of the summation with the Bernoulli coefficients  $ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{B_{2k}}{\left( 2k \right)!}\left( f^{2k-1}(n)-f^{2k-1}(1) \right)  $ where $f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{n}}$ and $ O\left(\frac{1}{n^{2-\frac{1}{n}}}\right) $

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}$ is constant. The $f$ terms are what count and the first term dominates.